# jquery news ticker is bugging when fading in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ticker

I'm trying to make a jquery news ticker.

I'm nearly there but its bugging out during the fade transition instead of smoothly fading to the next item.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to fix this? thanks

I think its something to do when its fading in/out as it shows both li's at once which then formats strangely

codepen link : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbajVG

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="news-ticker" data-speed="5000">
<div class="ticker-title">Important Announcements |</div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1....</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2....</li>
</ul>

<div class="ticker-nav">
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-stack-1x" style="color:white"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x" style="color:white"></i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
margin: 0;
background: #002653;
}

.news-ticker {
width: 70%;
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE, #C3C3C3);
color: #002653;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
border-radius:10px;
}

.news-ticker .ticker-title {
font-weight: 600;
float:left;
width:23%;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:0.08em;

}

.news-ticker ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}

.news-ticker li {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: left;
top: 50%;
list-style:none;
float:left;
}

.ticker-nav {
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 10px 0px 0px;
text-align: right;
top: 10%;
}

.news-ticker .fa-stack {
font-size: 1.5em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:2em;
}

.ticker-nav span {
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

jquery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 var tickerSpeed = $('.news-ticker').attr('data-speed');

 $('.news-ticker ul li').hide();
 $('.news-ticker ul li:first').show();

 var currentSlide = 0;
 var slideCount = ($('.news-ticker li').length) - 1;

 var startTicker = setInterval(function(){

 $('.news-ticker ul li').eq(currentSlide).fadeOut(500)

 if (currentSlide < slideCount) {
  currentSlide += 1;
 } else {
  currentSlide = 0;
 }

 $('.news-ticker ul li').eq(currentSlide).fadeIn(500)

 }, tickerSpeed);


 });
```

Comment: What should the animation look like? `$('.news-ticker ul li').hide();` sets `display:none` in which the `li` does not reserve space. `$('.news-ticker ul li').eq(currentSlide).fadeOut(500)` forces the element to be shown again, that's why both show up at the same time. If they should overlap while fading try `position:absolute` on `.news-ticker li`: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgvjdK](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgvjdK)

Comment: As @empiric said, `position: absolute` would be the way to go if you want them to fade on top of one another. You could position them in a parrent set to `position: relative` so that you don't have to position it manually.

Comment: Oh thanks guys! Oh I feel so stupid now for not spotting it before!! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you choose a `relative` position for the list elements.
You can't stack them on each other that way so at a short timespan both element are visible and the 2nd ist put below the 1st.

A simple solution would be to use a `absolute` position and change the positionings (top, left) accordingly to keep the current design

Like that:
([codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOXxLJ))

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var tickerSpeed = $('.news-ticker').attr('data-speed');

  $('.news-ticker ul li').hide();
  $('.news-ticker ul li:first').show();

  var currentSlide = 0;
  var slideCount = ($('.news-ticker li').length) - 1;

  var startTicker = setInterval(function() {

    $('.news-ticker ul li').eq(currentSlide).fadeOut(500)

    if (currentSlide < slideCount) {
      currentSlide += 1;
    } else {
      currentSlide = 0;
    }

    $('.news-ticker ul li').eq(currentSlide).fadeIn(500)

  }, tickerSpeed);


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #002653;
}

.news-ticker {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FEFEFE, #C3C3C3);
  color: #002653;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.news-ticker .ticker-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
}

.news-ticker ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.news-ticker li {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  top: 33%;
  left: 30%;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.ticker-nav {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  top: 10%;
}

.news-ticker .fa-stack {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2em;
}

.ticker-nav span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="news-ticker" data-speed="5000">
    <div class="ticker-title">!</div>
    <ul>
      <li> ------------ </li>
      <li> |||||||||||| </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="ticker-nav">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
      <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-stack-1x" style="color:white"></i>
    </span>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
      <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x" style="color:white"></i>
    </span>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: Here is a fork of the original pen using flexbox to not place the children using absolute units : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqEoWg (although it requires a min-height for the ul containing the ticker's items). Using transforms could be another possibility.

Comment: @Jake thanks for taking the time to smooth it. Be aware though that flexbox is till this day not supported by every browser

Comment: When implementing it using auto-prefixer or other prefixing solutions and being aware of the known bugs (mostly IE) I would say it is safe to use (see the [Can I Use page](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) and [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs))